# logic with socket.io / and node / react

Tags: node.js, reactjs, socket.io

when a user logs in to the site, I save their data to local storage and send it to my backend with a socket:

```
const player = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
this.socket.emit('addPlayer-Queue', player);
```

And on my back end getting this data
I will put this player in a queue, waiting for a next player to come in

in my back end:

```
  socket.on('addPlayer-Queue', (result) => {
      const player = {
        id: result.id,
        name: result.name,
        mmr: result.mmr
      }
      queue.addPlayer(player)
      const makeMatch =  queue.searching(player.id);   
      console.log(makeMatch);
      console.log(queue);
  socket.emit('match', makeMatch) 
  });
```

I add the player to the queue and look for an opponent for him using this function

```
  searching(id) {
    const firstPLayer = this.players.find(p => p.id == id)
    const { mmr } = firstPLayer
    const secondPlayer = this.players.find((playerTwo) => playerTwo.mmr < (5 / 100) * mmr + mmr && playerTwo.mmr > mmr - ((5 / 100) * mmr) && playerTwo.id != firstPLayer.id);
    if(!secondPlayer){
      return null;
    }
    const matchedPlayers = [
      firstPLayer,
      secondPlayer
    ]
    // remove matched players from this.players
    this.removePlayers(matchedPlayers);
    // return new Match with matched players
    return matchedPlayers;
  }
```

If there is an opponent I will return an array with player + the opponent if I don't find the opponent I will send null to my front end

and on my front end I keep listening to my event:

```
  this.socket.on('match', (result) => {
      if(!result){
        console.log('sem match');
      }
      else{
        this.setState({
          players: result
        })
      }

    });
```

I enter with the first user, and then my state players will be null
because I didn't find an opponent for him

When I enter the second account

in my back end i will already have my player one in queue, and then with this new user in queue i can form a battle so i would not have null in my players would return an array with both players like this:

```
Array(2)
0: {id: 3, name: "test", mmr: 1000}
1: {id: 2, name: "spt", mmr: 1000}
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)
```

But I'm wondering how I could get this to my player one?

because my state.players is still null
it remains an empty array, even though it has found a match for it.
like this:
[]

I don't know if I could do anything about it, and I also think what if I had 4 players queuing at the same time?
would i have a problem?

my front end:;

```
 import React, { Component } from 'react';
import io from 'socket.io-client';
import Loading from './Loading'
import Players from './Players'
class Home extends Component {

  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
    this.socket = null;
    this.state = {
      queue: [],
      loading: true,
      players: [],
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // io() not io.connect()
    this.socket = io('http://localhost:9000');

    const player = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
    this.socket.emit('addPlayer-Queue', player);
    this.socket.on('match', (result) => {
      if(!result){
        console.log('sem match');
      }
      else{
        this.setState({
          players: result
        })
      }

    });
/*
      this.socket.on('queue', (queue) => {
        console.log('ae');
        if (queue === 1) {
          this.setState({
            queue: queue,
            loading: false,
          })
        }else if(queue != 1)
        this.setState({
          queue: queue,
          loading: true,
        })
      });*/

    this.socket.open();
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.socket.close();
  }
  render() {
    const { queue } = this.state;
    const { loading } = this.state;
    const { players } = this.state
    const visibility = loading ? 'hidden' : 'visible';
    return (
     <div className="container">

       <div className="result">
       </div>
       <div className="ctnFlex">
    <div className="playerOne">{players.map(pls => <p>{pls.name}</p>)}</div>

           <Loading loading={loading} message='in queue.' />
         <div className="playerTwo" style={{ visibility }}>
         <Players players={players}/>
         </div>

       </div>

     </div>
   )
   }
}

export default Home;
```

ss with first account queuing

[image]

ss with second account queuing

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you have a design problem. You need to decouple the matching algorithm from the player registration. On the server you should have a timed event that matches players up rather than just doing it when players join, because then, as you have found, only the newly joining player will get the event. I can't write the code for you, but the rough idea is this:

- Keep an array of unmatched players
- When a player registers, add them to the unmatched player array
- When the server starts, use `setInterval(matchPlayers, 1000)` to run your matching every 1 second (for example).
- matchPlayers looks at your unmatched players array, and if it has > 1 player in it, it creates a match and emits a `match` event to the players' sockets. (It's not clear how you track which events get sent to which players).

Use setInterval to run the matching every couple of seconds or so and send match events to the relevant sockets. It's not clear how you associate

In general I would say there is not enough 'separation of concerns' in your code. For example, you have the code that sets state on the front end component right inside the socket event handler. That is too tight a coupling. Rather you should have all your socket handling code inside its own service and send events from there to your components, for instance via redux, or some other event system.

Comment: thanks for awnser  
Could you tell me more how I could do this?
I was a little confused:
You need to decouple the matching algorithm from the player registration

Comment: and about separation of concerns
if you can give me an example please
I would be very grateful

Comment: I tried to do something using timer
Could you tell me how I can improve?

https://pastebin.com/wENYvKxx

Comment: How do you associate players with sockets?

Comment: so far i didn't do any joining i didn't think it was necessary but i could put a socket.id field in my class players

Comment: Well you will want to send some events to some players and others not. If each player has a socket associated with them, then you can call your matching algorithm when each player registers, and emit the match event to each player's socket. On second thoughts, a timer may not be essential since the array of unmatched players only changes when players register or drop off.

Comment: Yes I really can't imagine how to solve this problem of waiting to find an opponent

I don't know if timer would be good

In case I will try to improve my code and add the socket id,
could you give me a light?

I try to do with a timer or is there any better possibility?

Comment: Thinking about saving the socket id

when a second player enters

would form a match

I could get this socket id to do some checking I don't know, 
or just add queued players
and when a match is formed
would get the scoket id from the players
and would send by socket
I don't know if this is possible, but it seems to me something viable

Comment: Yes, the latter idea. Without seeing your whole code, I can't provide much further light, but you definitely need a mechanism to associate players with sockets so you can route the relevant events to them.

Comment: Could you give me a light on the best way to associate the two?

Would it be putting the socketID in the player constructor?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203286/discussion-between-see-sharper-and-gabriel).

Comment: Hello friend sorry for forgetting to vote positive,
Could you help me with just one more thing?
I'm thinking of a way on how to match without sending an id as a base

that is

I'm trying to follow what you told me I created a session map of sockets

but I can't imagine how I could do to select two players in the queue that meet a condition